# Extracting Raster Values by Polyline End Points using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, spatial-analyst, network-analyst

I am looking for a way to extract elevations of end points for line data in ArcMap 10.2. I have a road dataset that I want to use as a Network Dataset in Network Analyst. I want to be able to set the elevation change from the beginning of the line to the end of the line.

So I can implement the elevation similar to what they have [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Exercise_1_Creating_a_network_dataset/00470000005t000000/) in step 20.

The data available: Roads Dataset, 5m DEM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Feature Vertices to Points (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000003p000000) tool followed by [Extract Values to Points (Spatial Analyst)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z0000002t000000) using the elevation value from your DEM. You can then calculate the difference to obtain the change in elevation.

If you're working with an entire road dataset you might want to take a look at the image below to determine the points you want to derive from vertices.

[image]