# Extracting lateral averages using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, contour

I want to do the following: to calculate the lateral average value of the surface aspect of a glacier (i.e. the average along a specific contour, the greenish lines).

Can someone help me or say how this can be done?

[image]

Comment: If you omit the step 1, I think [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/174367/extracting-raster-values-to-polyline-feature/174368) has answer to your question.